# Angular 5 - Indent for each iteration

Tags: javascript, angular

I am displaying values in an HTML table such as

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let employee of employeeList; let i = index">
      <td> {{i}} {{ employee.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ employee.address }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

What I need is that in the employee.name cell there should be 0 space for first employee, one space for 2nd employee, 2 spaces for 3rd employee and so on.

So, the result should look something like

```
  John         Chicago
   Thomas      London
    Anna       New York
```

Using i = index, I am able to get the index for each row. However, I am unable to make out how to translate each index to a space.

Comment: what about [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2k8vgh?file=src/app/heroes/heroes.component.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a unicode literal for a non breaking space:

```
spaces(num) {
 let spaces = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
   spaces += '\u00A0';
 }
 return spaces;
}
```

And call it in your html like:

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let employee of employeeList; let i = index">
    <td>{{spaces(i)}}{{employee.name}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.address}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2):

How about creating a `spaces` component that shows the number of spaces you want and use it in your loop :

SpacesComponent :

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let i of numbers">
    &nbsp;
</ng-container>
```

Usage :

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let name of ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']; let i = index">
  <spaces [count]="i"></spaces> {{ name }}<br/>
<ng-container>
```

[Here is a running example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49064244?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)